# ExpandableListView Seekbar in child

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview, seekbar

I have an ExpandableListView with a custom adapter. I have added a SeekBar in the single child of each group. I was able to expand the groups and view and even slide the SeekBar. However, I would like to be able to change a value in a TextView in the parent group based on the change. So my question is, how do I access the parent group view and a TextView in that from within the child?

I have tried: (in the custom BaseExpandableListAdapter)

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.anassignmentsliderchild, parent, false);
    }
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.assignmentSlider);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mainList.get(groupPosition).score = progress;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
/********************

I need something here instead of notifyDataSetChanged() that will change the child's parent's textview text, because all touches are lost when notifying

********************/
            }

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
});    
return convertView;
}
```

but when changing, all touches are lost due to the notification.

Comment: in getChildView you are getting groupPosition with this you can change group element

Comment: @Pravin Yes that is what I did, but I need to be able to notify the activity of that change.

Comment: GroupModel group = (GroupModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
        group.setScore(seekBar.getProgress()); and then notifyDataSetChanged();